# Why changes the focus to the entry when I click the label? Xamarin.Forms/UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, focus

I have a problem and I made an example to show it.

This code establishes two pairs of label/entry. If I have the focus set to the 2nd entry and I click the 2nd label, the focus goes to the 1st entry (!?)...

I need the ScrollView because in the real app, there are a lot of views that need to be scrolled.

I tried this in a UWP project on a Win10/11 PC.

How can this strange behavior be avoided?

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TestForm.MainPage">
    
    <ScrollView x:Name="scroll">
        <StackLayout>

            <Label Text="Title01"/>
            <Entry/>

            <Label Text="Title02"/>
            <Entry/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It seems a little abstract question, but one of the consecuences is that if you have a lot of views and click on a label at the bottom, it will scroll to the first entry, being this very confusing for the user

Comment: Have you test it on other platform? Is it only uwp issue?

Comment: I just tried on Android and this problem doesn't exist on this platform... I couldn't test it on iOS... I think it's just a uwp problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in UWP. See the references below. I hope this will be solved in netMaui...

[[Bug] Erroneous behavior: Why changes the focus to the entry when I click the label? Xamarin.Forms/UWP #15180](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15180#issuecomment-1050788593)

[ScrollView Jumps when Non-Interactable Element is Clicked #5652](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5652#issue-423735171)

[ScrollViewer Jumps to Top-most TextBox (UWP app) #597](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/597#issue-435622383)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add the TapGestureRecognizer on stacklayout to set unfous on first entry like:

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TestForm.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>

 <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
           Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <ScrollView x:Name="scroll">
        <StackLayout>
      <Button HeightRequest="0" WidthRequest="1" />//add button
            <Label Text="Title01"/>
            <Entry x:Name="entry1"/>

            <Label Text="Title02"/>
            <Entry/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**code behind:**

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 if(!entry1.isFocused)
  {entry1.Unfocus(); }
  
}
```

Comment: Dear  Adrain Zhu -MSFT , I tested your code but it still produces the same strange behavior...  :-(

Comment: In UWP it is by design that when the StackLayout gets tapped the system will search element for-each in the StackLayout until the first one which can be focused on.So, you can add an invisible button on the top as a workaround.

Comment: Dear Adrain Zhu -MSFT, thank you very much for your suggestions... I've tried your XAML C# and entry1 doesn't get the focus, but... the scrollView scrolls to the top when you test with several couples of label/entry and do click in, for example, the last label....this is very confusing for the user

Comment: maybe you can post this issue on xamarin forms to see if they can do something about it https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: ok, I think it's a good idea. I'll do it. Thank you Adrain Zhu for your help and patience!

Comment: I posted it on Xamarin.Forms issues, on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15180